# Headers from package 'fancyhdr' not showing

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am currently having trouble with headers from the package "fancydhr". More specifically, they don't show in the document despite the fact I'm explicitly defining them in the preamble of the document. (PS: headers shall not be displayed in the first page of each chapter).

A minimum reproductible example is the following:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Section \thesection\,  - \chaptername}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.20pt}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain} 
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Example 1}

\section{Sample}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{document}
```

The last page of the document should contain the header defined in the preamble. I was wondering if I've missed any command from the manual.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Greetings.

Comment: You use `\pagestyle{plain}` in the beginning of the document. This means all pages will only have a page number at the bottom, and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My apologies, I forgot to delete that, thanks for remarking that, Pieter. However, if you remove said instruction from my code, the header renders incorrectly: the line doesn't reach the designated margin. Why does that occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the fancyhdr setup after setting the geometry of the page.

```
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Section \thesection\,  - \chaptername}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.20pt}

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

[image: x]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time